# How to transfer files from Network File Folder(Remote server) to Azure Data Lake using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, remote-server, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

Is it possible to transfer files from remote file server to Azure Data Lake using Azure Data Factory.

As per my knowledge self-hosted IR would be helpful but i'm not sure where to configure the IR machine.

Help me guys if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Install IR on your remote server where you are getting the files from.

Follow the prerequisites provide in this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system?tabs=data-factory#prerequisites) to configure Self-hosted IR.

You can also refer [Considerations for using a self-hosted IR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#considerations-for-using-a-self-hosted-ir) document for more information on using Self-hosted IR.